# Dual Booting Ubuntu with Windows 10 RAM Problem

Tags: grub2

So my computer is running windows 10 (from windows 7) and I decided to dual-boot it with Ubuntu. I encountered this stubborn problem; I have 2 slots for ddr3 ram and  I placed 4GB and 2GB of sticks on them, which was working properly but after some time the task manager on windows shows that I have  2gb of ram on hardware reserved. I tried to check this on htop and it shows the same thing. Is it possible that GRUB is putting the ram on reserved? I tried CMOS reset, some simple configuration on windows 10, running the pc without the gpu, but nothing worked permanently. Is there any solution on this on Ubuntu? Thanks.

```
    OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version 10.0.18362 Build 18362
Other OS Description    Not Available
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
System Name NIMITZ
System Manufacturer Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
System Model    To be filled by O.E.M.
System Type x64-based PC
System SKU  To be filled by O.E.M.
Processor   AMD A4-3400 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics, 2700 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 2 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date   American Megatrends Inc. FA, 9/21/2012
SMBIOS Version  2.7
Embedded Controller Version 255.255
BIOS Mode   Legacy
BaseBoard Manufacturer  Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
BaseBoard Product   A55M-DS2
BaseBoard Version   x.x
Platform Role   Desktop
Secure Boot State   Unsupported
PCR7 Configuration  Binding Not Possible
Windows Directory   C:\Windows
System Directory    C:\Windows\system32
Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume1
Locale  United States
Hardware Abstraction Layer  Version = "10.0.18362.387"
User Name   NIMITZ\Hernandez
Time Zone   Malay Peninsula Standard Time
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 6.00 GB
Total Physical Memory   3.98 GB
Available Physical Memory   1.17 GB
Total Virtual Memory    5.98 GB
Available Virtual Memory    2.67 GB
Page File Space 2.00 GB
Page File   C:\pagefile.sys
Kernel DMA Protection   Off
Virtualization-based security   Not enabled
Device Encryption Support   Reasons for failed automatic device encryption: TPM is not usable, PCR7 binding is not supported, Hardware Security Test Interface failed and device is not Modern Standby, Un-allowed DMA capable bus/device(s) detected, TPM is not usable
Hyper-V - VM Monitor Mode Extensions    Yes
Hyper-V - Second Level Address Translation Extensions   Yes
Hyper-V - Virtualization Enabled in Firmware    Yes
Hyper-V - Data Execution Protection Yes
```

[image]

Comment: [EDIT] answer with output of ```sudo lshw -class memory ``` in linux terminal.

Comment: @Fortem Please also click [edit] and give us the make and model of your PC. Get the model from the serial number sticker; 'model' numbers from anyplace else aren't the real model number needed to find specs. Please don't use Add Comment; instead, please click [edit].

Comment: @karel  i also tried switching the placement of the ram, i can say that it is possible that one of the ram slots is being hindered by a software setting from being usable (i successfully booted using both of the rams sticks but not on both slots) coz windows can detect all of the ram. plus memtest also detects both of it.

Comment: Do you have dual channel mode on? Your manual says this "When enabling Dual Channel mode with two memory modules, it is recommended that memory of 2.the same capacity, brand, speed, and chips be used for optimum perform"

Comment: Do you use 32-bit OS?  Maybe something went wrong with pae/iommu settings.